# $\textbf{TI-84}$: Why do I get error data type with lists?

Tags: statistics, calculator

In my $L1$ list, I have the values $\{0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6\}$. I want to program my $L2$ list to calculate $Pr(X < x)$ for each value of $x$ in $L1$, using a normal distribution.

So this is what I'm doing: I go up and highlight $L2$, and then call $normalcdf$, with the lower bounds at $-10^{10}$, the upper bound at $L1$, $\mu = 0$, and $\sigma = 1$. When I click enter, I get Error: Data Type. I think it has to do with me typing in $L1$ for the upper bounds, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Can someone please show me the proper way of doing this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this in for `L2`:

`seq(normalcdf(-10^10, L1(X), 0, 1), X, 1, 4)`

You can find the `seq()` function by going to `2nd`-> `LIST`->`OPS`-> `#5`

`seq()` basically allows you to create a list ("sequence") of items by iterating an expression over the variable you pick (in the expression above, I used `X`). The above expression is basically saying apply the `normalcdf()` function to each item (1 thru 4) in `L1` and put the results into a new list in order.